# Servicestack GlobalRequestFilters populating additional user auth data into Jwt tokens

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, servicestack

I want to add additional properties to the response when a user logs in.

When calling https://Servicestackservice/auth/credentials?userName=****&password=****  I get the below response. I want to add 2 additional values.  DateFormat & TimeZone

{
    "userId": "21",
    "sessionId": "****",
    "userName": "SystemAdmin",
    "displayName": "System Admin",
    "referrerUrl": null,
    "bearerToken": "****",
    "refreshToken": ***",
    "profileUrl": ***",
    "roles": [ View
    ],
    "permissions": [ View
    ],
    "responseStatus": {
        "errorCode": null,
        "message": null,
        "stackTrace": null,
        "errors": null,
        "meta": null
    },
    "meta": null
}

[I found an example from the SS forums.](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/access-custom-user-session-and-request/1997) I had to modify it some to make it run.

[From the SS docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload)

```
Modifying the Payload
```

Whilst only limited info is embedded in the payload by default, **all matching AuthUserSession properties embedded in the token will also be populated on the Session**, which you can add to the payload using the CreatePayloadFilter delegate. So if you also want to have access to when the user was registered you can add it to the payload with:

I am hoping this is how i get them into the "**matching AuthUserSession**"

```
          this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add(async (req, res, requestDto) =>
            {
                AuthFilter.AuthResponse(req, res, requestDto);
            });

        public static void AuthResponse(IRequest req, IResponse res, object response)
    {
        var authRes = response as Authenticate;
        if (authRes == null || authRes.UserName == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var session = (CustomUserSession)req.GetSession();
        if (session != null && session.UserAuthId != null)
        {
            //General Format for US
            string dformat = "g";
            using (var db = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
            {
                var userAuthExt = db.Single<UserAuthExtension>(ext => ext.UserAuthId == int.Parse(session.UserAuthId));
                if (userAuthExt != null)
                {
                    dformat = userAuthExt.DateTimeFormat;
                }
            }

            authRes.Meta = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"TimeZone", session.TimeZone}, {"DateFormat", dformat}};
        }
    }
```

Adding this to try to get the JWT tokens to hold the new data. Examining the payload i can see the 2 new values are added to the list.

```
   new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings)
                    {
                        CreatePayloadFilter = (payload, session) =>
                        {

                            if (session != null && session.UserAuthId != null)
                            {
                                //General Format for US
                                string dformat = "g";
                                using (var db = HostContext.TryResolve<IDbConnectionFactory>().Open())
                                {
                                    var userAuthExt = db.Single<UserAuthExtension>(ext => ext.UserAuthId == int.Parse(session.UserAuthId));
                                    if (userAuthExt != null)
                                    {
                                        dformat = userAuthExt.DateTimeFormat;
                                    }
                                }

                                payload["TimeZone"] = ((AuthUserSession) session).TimeZone;
                                payload["DateFormat"] = dformat;
                            }
                        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link to the docs you're referring to, which I believe is ServiceStack's JWT [Modifying the Payload](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload) docs. Although it's not clear which example in the [Customer Forums](https://forums.servicestack.net/) you're referring to.

It's also not clear what the question is, I'm assuming it's this statement:

> When calling /auth/credentials?userName=****&password=**** I do not see the new values.

Where exactly are you expecting these values? If you're authenticating by credentials you're not Authenticating by JWT so you will not have these additional properties populated on your User Session. If they're embedded in your JWT's body payload then as `TimeZone` is a AuthUserSession property, it [should be populated](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/UserAuth.cs#L479-L481) if it was contained within the JWT payload:

```
case "TimeZone":
    authSession.TimeZone = entry.Value;
    break;
```

But `DateFormat` is not an `AuthUserSession` property so you will need to populate it manually by providing an implementation for `PopulateSessionFilter`, e.g:

```
new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings) 
{
    PopulateSessionFilter = (session,payload,req) => 
        session.Meta["DateFormat"] = payload["DateFormat"];
}
```

But these properties are only going populated in the Users Session when authenticating via JWT.

To help diagnose any issues you should but a breakpoint in your `CreatePayloadFilter` to see what you've populated the JWT payload with and conversely put a breakpoint in your `PopulateSessionFilter` to inspect what's contained in the payload and resulting populated session.

Comment: Updated my question. When calling https://Servicestackservice/auth/credentials?userName=****&password=**** I want to add 2 additional values. DateFormat & TimeZone. Seems this is not the correct approach for adding to the login response.

Comment: @SteveColeman It's still not clear what this has to do with JWT? When you authenticate via credentials you're using via the `CredentialsAuthProvider` which as [per my answer](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/access-custom-user-session-and-request/1997/2?u=mythz) returns the fixed [AuthenticateResponse](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Client/AuthDtos.cs#L12) DTO. You can populate its `Meta` Dictionary with a [Global Response Filter](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/access-custom-user-session-and-request/1997/15?u=mythz) or with a Custom AuthProvider.

Comment: Doh, got it now.  this.GlobalRequestFilters.Add should have been  this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add After that the above code works fine.